# Adding a directory in CVS

Tags: cvs

I am new to CVS and have these two questions, I am not sure if they might sound silly:

1. I see a CVS directory in my checked out version of project database. Now, If I have created a directory and created new files in it, first I need to add the directory followed by adding the files and checking in the files. My question is, in the directory path how do I add the directory named 'CVS'? Otherwise I am unable to add or checking in the newly created directory. Rather how and when the 'CVS' directory gets created and added in a database?
2. When I added a directory with CVS add command, all the sub directories got displayed starting with a question mark. For example:

   ```
     cvs add MAC_Flow_Control/
     ? MAC_Flow_Control/Illegal_Pause
     ? MAC_Flow_Control/Pause_Frame
   ```

Why question mark is getting displayed? Is it an error?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The `CVS` directory is created when you add the new directory using `cvs add`.

Doing a `cvs add` on a directory is not recursive, so any subdirectories will show up with a `?` as they are unknown to CVS. New files will also show up with a `?`.